# How can I force window.location to make an HTTP request instead of using the cache?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

In my web application I am setting `window.location` to navigate to a different page, but for some reason Firefox shows an old version of that page.

Using Firebug I detected that the browser doesn't even send an HTTP request, it simply uses an older version of that page (not even the last one) and displays it.

The page itself has [all the usual headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068407/23368) to prevent caching which works perfectly when I browse my pages using links or manual input. The problem only occurs when seting `window.location`.

Is this a Firefox problem or something to expect from any browser? Can this behaviour be changed?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could just add a random parameter to the page URL in order to have the browser issue a new request.

So instead of using

```
 window.location = "my.url/index.html";
```

use

```
 window.location = "my.url/index.html?nocache=" + (new Date()).getTime();
```

Comment: The good old cache buster :) I'm using it right now, but I'm also interested in some background info, like if this is the designed behaviour of `window.location` or if I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: If your page was served with http headers that say not to cache the page I don't think it would be chached. But if it isn't served with "no cache" headers  it is a good behavior to cache it as much as possible to save bandwith. Cahcning may occur both in the users browser and in various internet equipment such as proxies. A better way would thus be to control the caching of the page. But the "cache buster" is the easy way...

Answer (score 6):

You can use location.reload with a true argument, which will always bypass the cache.

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: This reloads only the actual site. This command can not be used to navigate to any other site with bypassing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Add some time specific or random querystring value to the url. This will force the page to be reloaded.

```
var yourNewLoc = "http://newlocation.com/";
document.location = yourNewLoc + "?c=" + (new Date()).valueOf();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate if there is any existing query parameter in the url. If any query parameter exist, you should append the timestamp using "&". I have written a quick snippet that might be of your help.

```
window.newLocation = function( location ) {
    var newLocation = ( typeof location === "string" ) ? location : window.location.href,
       appendType = ( newLocation.indexOf("?") < 0 ) ? "?" : "&";
    window.location = newLocation + appendType + "_t=" + (new Date()).getTime();
}
```

Usage:

```
newLocation("index.html") or window.newLocation("index.html") 
// opens "index.html?_t=<timstamp>"

newLocation("index.html?existingQuery=true") or window.newLocation("index.html?existingQuery=true") 
// opens "index.html?existingQuery=true&_t=<timstamp

newLocation() or window.newLocation() 
// opens existing window location with a timestamp
```

You could further modify the snippet to remove exiting timestamp in the query parameter to avoid duplication

Answer (score 0):

just need to tell your download function (in the controller, in case of Laravel) do not cache it by setting the headers, used the following code for Laravel:

```
$headers =[
            'Content-Type' => 'application/text',
            'Cache-Control' => 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0',
            'Cache-Control' => 'post-check=0, pre-check=0, false',
             'Pragma' => 'no-cache',  ];
return response()->file($pathToFile, $headers);
```

This code is very much true for PhP as well just need transferring the code accordingly. By adding new dates may invalidate a link especially if you are using a temporarySignedLink etc.

Cheers