# Back button on browser making no-cached page accessible

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm testing this ephemeral images functionality in an HTML document (a la Snapchat).

My images are visible for X seconds, after which the page reloads and the displayed images are gone. Sidestepping the myriad ways someone can save an image like that, I'm squarely focused on the **refresh** functionality at the moment.

My JS code to refresh the page is as follows:

```
<script>
window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.location = "example.com/page.html?nocache=" + (new Date()).getTime();
}, 5000); // refresh/redirect after 5 seconds.
</script>
```

I've written code that destroys the image after a single refresh - so the above trigger works perfectly. But the problem is the **back button** on the browser. If you press it, you simply get to see the image again. Game over!

I've already included the following meta tags in my HTML document, but they're not helping:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=0">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

Is there any way to ensure the browser back button is removed from the equation, or its effect neutralized? Please advise.

Comment: Store the image in a session variable that is destroyed when the user navigates away from the page or is wiped clean before being set when the user first arrives at the page - assuming you only want your users to be able to see it once and preserved nowhere.

Comment: @Lewis that wont solve the back button problem the OP has. Modern browsers wont do a refresh of the page if you press the back button.

Comment: @t.niese Wouldn't it be destroyed if it specifically does so at the top of the page? For example, if you store the image in `$_SESSION['image']` and wipe this variable before setting it again on every page load, ie, `$_SESSION['image'] = ''`, wouldn't this then be blank when the user presses the back button? I am possibly misunderstanding how the back button actually works.

Comment: kill the image `onunload` so you can't back() into it. `history.replaceState()` can also be utilized instead of `location=` to make back() "go back 2", and thus to the page before the img

Comment: Does the refresh have any function other than removing the image? If not, just remove the image instead of refreshing, then there's no version to go back to.

Comment: @Lewis `$_SESSION` is server side and php related. The back button is client side and cache related. Hitting the back button does not necessarily result in a new request to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't refresh the page, instead use simple DOM manipulation to remove the image. If you have jQuery loaded, you can easily do it like so:

```
<script>
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $( 'img' ).remove();
}, 5000); // refresh/redirect after 5 seconds.
</script>
```

(You'll want to use a more specific selector if you have more than one image on the page)

To load a new image in this context, you'll need to use an AJAX request, and set a new timer. But this will cause the back button to not bring the image back.